# NASM Segmentation fault at cmp

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm new to NASM, and I decided to write my first actual program (which is a simple calculator). But I've encountered a "segmentation fault" error in runtime. As I figured out, the issue was in "cmp byte[ebx], 0" line in "len" procedure, which is called first from "check_op" which, in turn, is called from "jmp check_op" in "_start". The idea was to calculate the output value, and concatenate the output string like "num1 + '+' + num2 + '=' + num3 + '.'" for sum.
Here's that procedure (it calculates the string's length in runtime, string is in ebx register, length will be in ecx):

```
len:
    push ebx
    mov ecx, 0
    dec ebx
    count:
        inc ecx
        inc ebx
        cmp byte[ebx], 0
        jnz count
    dec ecx
    pop ebx
    ret
```

and the full code:

```
section .data
msg1 db 'Enter number 1:'
len1 equ $ - msg1
msg2 db 'Enter number 2:'
len2 equ $ - msg2
msg3 db 'Operation (+, -, *, /):'
len3 equ $ - msg3
msg4 db 'abc'
len4 equ $ - msg4
msgerr db 'Operand error.'
lenerr equ $ - msgerr
reserve equ 8
SYS_WRITE equ 4
SYS_READ equ 3
SYS_EXIT equ 1
STDOUT equ 1
STDIN equ 2
STDEX equ 0

section .bss
num1 resb reserve
num2 resb reserve
op resb reserve
outmsg resb 16

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    call read1
    call read2
    call read3
    jmp check_op

read1:
    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx, STDOUT
    mov ecx, msg1
    mov edx, len1
    int 80h

    mov eax, SYS_READ
    mov ebx, STDIN
    mov ecx, num1
    mov edx, reserve
    int 80h
    ret
    
read2:
    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx, STDOUT
    mov ecx, msg2
    mov edx, len2
    int 80h

    mov eax, SYS_READ
    mov ebx, STDIN
    mov ecx, num2
    mov edx, reserve
    int 80h
    ret

read3:
    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx, STDOUT
    mov ecx, msg3
    mov edx, len3
    int 80h

    mov eax, SYS_READ
    mov ebx, STDIN
    mov ecx, op
    mov edx, reserve
    int 80h
    ret

check_op:
    mov esi, op
    mov edi, '+'
    mov ebx, edi
    call len
    cld
    repe  cmpsb
    jecxz F1
    ;cmp op, '-'
    ;je F2
    ;cmp op, '*'
    ;je F3
    ;cmp op, '/'
    ;je F4
    jmp ERR

len:
    push ebx
    mov ecx, 0
    dec ebx
    count:
        inc ecx
        inc ebx
        cmp byte[ebx], 0
        jnz count
    dec ecx
    pop ebx
    ret

F1:
    outlist times 3 dd 0
    addlist dd '+', '=', '.'
    mov ecx, outlist
    mov eax, [num1]
    mov dword[ecx], eax
    add ecx, 1
    mov ebx, [num2]
    mov dword[ecx], ebx
    add ecx, 1
    add eax, ebx
    mov dword[ecx], eax
    
    mov edx, ecx
    xor ecx, ecx
    mov eax, addlist
    copy:
        mov ebx, [edx]
        call len
        mov esi, [edx]
        mov edi, outmsg
        cld
        rep movsb
        mov ebx, [edx]
        call len
        mov esi, [eax]
        mov edi, outmsg
        cld
        rep movsb
        inc edx
        inc eax
        cmp dword[edx], 0
        jne copy
    
    mov ebx, outmsg
    call len
    mov ecx, edx

    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx, STDOUT
    mov ecx, outmsg
    int 80h
    jmp exit

ERR:
    mov eax, SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx, STDOUT
    mov ecx, msgerr
    mov edx, lenerr
    int 80h
    jmp exit

exit:
    mov eax, SYS_EXIT
    mov ebx, STDEX
    int 80h
```

I haven't finished the code yet, so I want for you only to help me with this error, and everything else I'll try to do myself for best experience.
Thanks.

UPD: The "len" function requires a string **pointer**, but, as I understood from first comments, the code gives an actual string to the function (tell me, if I'm wrong). How to give it the string's pointer and not the ascii code of the string?

Comment: Make sure that the value in your `ebx` register is a valid location in memory. If it's some arbitrary value this would be the cause of your segfault, as `byte[ebx]` means "8-bit value pointed to by `ebx`". The segfault isn't occurring at `cmp`, but rather at the `byte[ebx]` call.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply! I moved '+' to edi, then edi to ebx, then I called that len function. So, as I think, it should see the valid value in ebx register, or I do not understand something?

Comment: I think you're trying to treat the literal `'+'` character as a pointer when that's not your intention. Have you tried `cmp ebx, '+'`? And since a character is only 8-bits long you should be able to use `cmp bl, '+'` for clarity.

Comment: `mov edi, '+'` loads `edi` with the immediate value 43, i.e. the ASCII code of the character `+`, and then you move that value into `ebx`.  So `cmp byte [ebx], 0` is trying to fetch a byte from address 43 and compare it with 0.  Since no memory is mapped at address 43, crash.

Comment: There are an awful lot of places in your code where you're using dword-sized instructions (4 bytes) to process single bytes.  They are all going to have to be fixed.  You should learn about operand sizes.

Comment: @GuyMarino yes, there was a trial of simple cmp. I don't remember the actual error, when I did this, but there was one.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks, I'll try to fix those. But I can't understand, how can I replace the erroneous byte fetching...

Comment: If there's a different error, then please give a repro. If I remember correctly, there shouldn't be any problem with literal comparison.

Comment: @GuyMarino "invalid combination of opcode and operands"

Comment: Please try exactly `cmp bl, '+'`, I think it might be that NASM has an issue with your data widths.

Comment: It worked, thanks! But the thing is... are those issues in len procedure appear only when ebx contains a char instead of string? Because I have much more procedure calls in my code, and if this issues will continue to appear, I'll need to do something in procedure.

Comment: And for some reason after simple comparsion 'cmp ebx, op' never goes an je instruction 'je F1'. ('ebx' contains a '+' through 'mov ebx, '+' ', that actually make it work, and 'op' contains an operation that was given by user), even if I wrote '+'...

Comment: No, like I said, it's throughout your code.  Take for example the code around `F1`.  `mov eax, [num1]` is loading 4 bytes from memory, whereas there is only one byte of meaningful data at `num1`.  Likewise `mov dword[ecx], eax` is storing 4 bytes.  (You have another problem at `F1` in that you have data in the middle of your code; the CPU will attempt to execute them as instructions since it doesn't know any better.)

Comment: Basically, there are a lot of things in your code where you're treating assembly like a higher-level language.  In a HLL you can declare and define data intermixed with executable statements, and the compiler will sort it out.  Likewise in an HLL you can write a statement like `a=b+c` the same regardless of whether `a,b,c` are 8-bit, 16-bit-, 32-bit or whatever, and the compiler will generate the right instructions based on their declared types.  None of those things are true in assembly language.  You must take care of all those things yourself.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you for advice!

Comment: To load a byte into a full register, `movzx eax, byte [...]`

Comment: Thank you too, @PeterCordes

Comment: To pass a pointer to characters, they have to be in memory somewhere.  This is assembly language, so you have to decide where.  e.g. `section .rodata` / `my_str: db "+", 0`.  But don't call `len` when you know the length is 1, just `cmp byte [esi], '+'`, or better load it into a register where you can cmp it.

Comment: Okay, thanks for help!